# Make images stretch vertically 100% while keeping proportions

Tags: css

I already have a portfolio page [here](http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/studioartnouveau/sculpture-commissions/)

As you can see, images that are portraits fit well, images that are landscape do not. I need to find a way to make the landscape images fit 100% of the height but just not show anything horizontally outside of the container. Ideally I would like to do this without changing the HTML code (just using CSS). I don't mind if the items scale via height rather than width.

```css
.w-portfolio-item-image img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-portfolio-item order_1 sculpture-commissions">
  <div class="w-portfolio-item-h">
    <a class="w-portfolio-item-anchor" href="http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/studioartnouveau/portfolio/the-compassion/">
      <div class="w-portfolio-item-image">
        <img class="w-portfolio-item-image-first" src="http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/studioartnouveau/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SR4-The-Compassion-after-400x373.jpg" alt="The Compassion">
      </div>
      <div class="w-portfolio-item-meta">
        <div class="w-portfolio-item-meta-h">
          <h2 class="w-portfolio-item-title">The Compassion</h2>
          <span class="w-portfolio-item-text"></span>
          <span class="w-portfolio-item-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried just adding height:100% but it really stretches all the images. I want them all to stay proportional.

Comment: **Side note**: [playing music automatically is a really bad idea](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-dis-audio.html), especially for sight impaired visitors who navigate by listening to prompts. For those of us with good vision, it is just plain annoying.

Comment: Well you can remove img tag and in your div w-portfolio-item-image use this in css height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.inventivewebdesign.com/studioartnouveau/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SR4-The-Compassion-after-400x373.jpg');
    background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;    but it will change everything you have to declare hover effect for this div

Comment: I hate the sound too but that is requested by the client, no matter what I do to suggest against it. Maybe I will try the visually impaired approach.

Comment: L-X.... the problem is that I don't want to go in and recode the portfolio plugin that the wordpress theme is using. As I said I would just like to do it via CSS using the existing HTML.

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/xuqoverezo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DIV already scales accordingly,

set the image style inside the div to height 100% and width auto.
then set the DIV style overflow to hidden

Setting the DIV overflow to hidden will "crop" any information, image or otherwise, that extends past the set dimensions of your DIV